# Search for string within Collection of objects CollectionView

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to filter an ICollectionView, I want to filter it by the contents of an observable collection in each object of the IcollectionView.

Within the collectionView I have objects, each of these objects have a collection of objects called SomeObject, I want to filter the Collectionview by wether the Textsearch string appears in any of the SomeObjects objects within the collection.

I hope that makes sence...

I have attempted a few diffrent ways to no avail and im rather stuck :( I cant seem to get my head around this one. I think it requires some crazy LINQ, something that I have just started to learn.

```
View.Filter = new Predicate<object>(o => ((BasePropertyTypeVM)o).Properties.Contains(i => ((SomeProperty)i).Value.Contains(TextSearch)));

View.Filter = new Predicate<object>(o => ((BasePropertyTypeVM)o).Properties.Contains(new Predicate<object>( i => ((SomeProperty)i).Value.Contains(TextSearch);

View.Filter = new Predicate<object>(o => ((BasePropertyTypeVM)o).Properties.Where(i => i.Value.Contains(TextSearch)));
```

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: Try if this works (I didn't have the chance to test it): `View.Filter = o => ((BasePropertyTypeVM)o).Properties.Any(p => p.Contains(TextSearch));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Any**

It determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition.

```
View.Filter = new Predicate<object>(o => ((BasePropertyTypeVM)o).Properties.Any(i => i.Value.Contains(TextSearch)));
```